# Storing MySQL query results in an Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have a MySQL table, Users,  like this -

```
-----------------------------------------
ID      | FirstName    | LastName
-----------------------------------------
1       | ABC          | XYZ
2       | DEF          | LMN
3       | GHI          | PQR
-----------------------------------------
```

And I can fetch results using simple MySQL query like

> SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Users

Now what I am looking for is to store the query results in an associative array form. The structure would be something like this -

```
Array
(
[ID] => Array
(
[0] => FirstName
[1] => LastName
)
)
```

SO the above query result should get stored in an array like this -

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
  (
  [0] => ABC
  [1] => XYZ
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
  [0] => DEF
  [1] => LMN
  )
  [3] => Array
  (
  [0] => GHI
  [1] => PQR
  )
)
```

I know about array_push. But I wonder if that needs to be used. How can get this result ?

Comment: what are you using? mysql api? mysqli extension? pdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Users');

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $id = array_shift($row); // Shifts first element
  $data[$id] = $row; 
}
```

You can use inside while a shorter version `$data[array_shift($row)] = $row;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put in your Database connection informations, maybe change the SQL-Statement a bit and the column-names inside the while-loop.

```
$db = @new mysqli('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DBNAME');
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Users`");

$yourdata = array();

if ($res && $db->errno == 0) {
   while ($row == $res->fetch_object()) {
      $yourdata[$row->ID] = array(0 => $row->firstname, 1 => $row->lastname);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more associative than you wanted :)

```
$temp = array();
$arr = array();

$r = mysql_query("<your query>");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
   $temp['fname'] = $row['FirstName'];
   $temp['lname'] = $row['LastName'];
   $arr[$row['ID']] = $temp;
   unset($temp);
}
```

Should output

```
Array (
   [1] => Array (
       [fname]   => ABC
       [lname]   => XYZ
   )
)
.
.
.
etc
```